# Show $f^n=\mathrm{id}_A$ for some $n$ where $A$ is a finite set and $f : A \to A$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set and let $f: A \to A$ be a bijection. Show that  $f^n=\mathrm{id}_A$ for some $n > 0$.
I don't really understand how to prove it. And what does the notation $\mathrm{id}_A$ mean?

Comment: $id_A\ $ is the identity function, that is: $\ f:A\to A\ $ satisfying $\ f(a) = a\ \forall\ a\in A.$

Comment: The set $\{ f^n : n \in \mathbb N \}$ is finite.

Comment: If you know elementary group theory, then note that the set $\{ f^n : n \in \mathbb Z \}$ is a finite group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ \vert A\vert = k\in\mathbb{N}\ $ and let $\ a\in A.$

Suppose $\ \not\exists\ n\ $ such that $\ f^{n}(a) = a.\quad (\text{Supposition }1)$

Then, $\ f(a) \neq a\ $ (otherwise supposition $(1)$ would be false).

Next,  $\ f^2(a) \neq a\ $ (otherwise supposition $(1)$ would be false), and $\ f^2(a) \neq f(a)\ $ (else $\ f\ $ would not be bijective).

Next,  $\ f^3(a) \neq a\ $ (otherwise supposition $(1)$ would be false), and $\ f^3(a) \neq f^2(a)\ $ or $\ f(a)\ $ (else $\ f\ $ would not be bijective).

Continuing in this way, we see that $\ f^j(a)\ $ are all different (distinct) for each $\ j\in\mathbb{N},\ $ contradicting finiteness of set $A.\ $ Thus Supposition $(1)$ is false.

Since $\ a\ $ was arbitrary, we have the following:

For each $\ a_i\in A,\ \exists\ n_i\ $ such that $\ f^{n_i}(a_i) = a_i.$

So we see that,

$$ n = \prod_{i=1}^k n_i,\qquad \text{ or } \qquad n=lcm(n_1,\ldots,n_k) $$

has the property that $\ f^n = id_A.$

Answer (score 3):

As $A$ is finite  the set of bijections of $A$ is finite too. Therefore, for two numbers, $k \not =l$, on has $f^k=f^l$. Then, as $f$ is a bijection, $f^{k-l}=Id$.

Answer (score 1):

As lhf mentioned, the set $\{f^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a finite group under function composition (specifically, it's $\langle f \rangle \le \mathrm{S}_A$ where $\mathrm{S}_A$ is the symmetric group on $A$, and $\lvert \mathrm{S}_A \rvert = \lvert A\rvert!$).

The identity element in this group is $\mathrm{id}_A = f^0$.

As this is a group, there exists some $f^{-1} \in \langle f \rangle$ such that $f^{-1} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$, and as our group is generated by $f$, we know that $f^{-1} = f^m$ for some $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$. By the pigeonhole principle, we can even place an upper bound on $m$: we know that $m \le \lvert A \rvert! - 1$.

From here, we know that $\mathrm{id}_A = f^{-1} \circ f = f^m \circ f^1 = f^{m+1}$. Thus, setting $n := m+1$, we have $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \le \lvert A \rvert!$ such that $f^n = \mathrm{id}_A$.

Comment: My hint about finite groups was meant to use Lagrange's theorem...

Comment: "the set $\{f^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a finite group under function composition". Isn't OP'S question asking to prove that (part of) this is true though? You can't assume the thing you're trying to prove...

Comment: @Adam Maybe? There are only finitely-many ($n!$) permutations of a set of cardinality $n$ (bijections on a set of $n$ elements), and trivially the composition of bijections is a bijection (closure), and composition is associative. Inverses are supplied by bijectivity, and the identity function is the group identity. The rest follows from the pigeonhole principle and the injectivity of composition by a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that for every $x$ in $A$, there must exist some $n_x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{n_x}(x) = x$?

After that, if you take the smallest common multiple of all those $n_x$ (let's call it $N$), then $f^N(x)=x$ for every $x \in A$